# LaTeX interpreter in Octave fails a 'run-time test'

Tags: latex, octave

I am trying to create a plot in Octave using the LaTeX interpreter for the axis labels, but whenever I try to do so, using the following code:

```
figure()
xlabel('The $x$ axis','interpreter','latex')
```

Octave returns the following message:

`warning: latex_renderer: a run-time test failed and the 'latex' interpreter has been disabled.`

According to the online Octave documentation, it requires some external tools, all of which are present on my system.

> The "latex" interpreter only works if an external LaTeX tool chain is present. Three binaries are needed: latex, dvipng, and dvisvgm. If those binaries are installed but not on the path, one can still provide their respective path using the following environment variables: OCTAVE_LATEX_BINARY, OCTAVE_DVIPNG_BINARY, and OCTAVE_DVISVG_BINARY.

I even tried manually setting the aforementioned environment variables, using Octave's `setenv()` function, but no dice. I'm using Octave version 7.3.0, running on OpenSUSE. If there is a way I can get some more verbose output from Octave to help debug the issue I'm all ears.

Answer (score -1):

Just tested with the latest version of Octave

```
> octave --version
GNU Octave, version 8.4.0
```

and Tex Live 2023

```
> latex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023)
```

Everything works fine.

```
...
xlabel('This is $X$', "Interpreter", "latex");

expression = '$Z = X^2 + Y^2$';
annotation('textbox', [0.2, 0.9, 0.25, 0.25], 'String', 
           [expression], 'Interpreter', 'latex', 'FontSize', 
           14, 'EdgeColor','none');
...
```

[image: Screenshot:Label and Annotation with Latex expression]

Comment: I have Tex Live installed, it compiles normal LaTeX documents just fine. Also, changing the interpreter from "latex" to "tex" doesn't solve the issue. It does "work", in that it correctly interprets TeX commands and displays an appropriate label, but LaTeX contains additional features that the TeX interpreter cannot handle.

Comment: @user3308082 Just updated the answer, hopefully that helps.